# Which Excel VBA RegEx expression should I use to count decimal places?

Tags: regex, vba, excel-2003

**Q:** Which Excel VBA RegEx expression should I use to count decimal places?

**Desired output**
This is a table with some example input strings and the desired output.

```
INPUT       DESIRED OUTPUT
string      max value   unit    decimal places
--------------------------------------------------
200A        200         A       0
110kV       110         kV      0
38,1MW      38,1        MW      1
38,1Mvar    38,1        Mvar    1
0-130°C     130         C       0
20-130°C    130         C       0
2000A       2000        A       0
10 kV       10          V       0
34,6MW      34,6        MW      1
34,6Mvar    34,6        Mvar    1
600A        600         A       0
114,3 MW    114,3       MW      1
114,3 Mvar  114,3       Mvar    1
2500A       2500        A       0
300A        300         A       0
500 A       500         A       0
100A        100         A       0
```

**What I have done so far**
Here you see a standalone Excel VBA code. The first sub is only for testing.
The function `RegEx` is my issue.

```vb
Sub TestRegEx()
    strArray = Array("200 A", "200 A", "110 kV", "38,1MW", "38,1Mvar", _
            "0-130°C", "2000 A", "10 kV", "34,6MW", "34,6Mvar", "600 A", _
            "114,3 MW", "114,3 Mvar", "2500 A", "300 A", "500 A", "100 A")

    For i = 0 To UBound(strArray)
       Call RegEx(strArray(i))
    Next
End Sub

Function RegEx(ByVal strInput As String)

    Dim objRegEx As Object
    Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    objRegEx.IgnoreCase = True
    objRegEx.Global = True

    'Show me the value
    objRegEx.Pattern = "[^0-9_,]"
    Debug.Print objRegEx.Replace(strInput, "")

    'Show me the unit
    objRegEx.Pattern = "[^A-Z_°]"
    Debug.Print objRegEx.Replace(strInput, "")

    'Show me the decimal places
    objRegEx.Pattern = "?????"
    Debug.Print objRegEx.Replace(strInput, "")

End Function
```

**Hints**

- I want to avoid normal VBA methods like InStr or looping through every character.
- Maybe the VBA `Len` method can be used to count the length of a string. But it will fail if there are zero decimal places, or?
- For me, regular expressions are hard to read. All my knowledge is based on [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx).

I am  thankful for any help to my initial question on how to count decimal places.

---

PS: If you have suggestions for my other two RegEx strings for *unit* and *value*, please let me know. For example my *value* regex expression fails on "20-130°C".  I don't know how to remove everything left from "-" to extract the value "130" only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
Function RegExTest(ByVal strInput As String)
    Dim objRegEx As Object, ret$
    Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With objRegEx
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
        'printing value
        .Pattern = "[^0-9_,]"
        Debug.Print .Replace(strInput, "")
        ret = .Replace(strInput, "") & vbTab

        'printing unit
        .Pattern = "[^A-Z_°]"
        Debug.Print .Replace(strInput, "")
        ret = ret & .Replace(strInput, "") & vbTab

        'printing decimal places
        .Pattern = ","
        Debug.Print .Execute(strInput).Count
        ret = ret & CStr(.Execute(strInput).Count)
    End With
    RegExTest = ret
End Function
```

**UPDATE**

To remove parts before `-`, use the below function:

```
Function RegExTest(ByVal strInput As String)
    Dim objRegEx As Object, ret$
    Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With objRegEx
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True

        'printing value
        .Pattern = "[^0-9_,-]"'///<--do not delete hyphen now.
        Dim temp$
        temp = .Replace(strInput, "")
        .Pattern = "^.*?-"'///<-remove hyphen according to your need
        temp = .Replace(temp, "")
        Debug.Print temp
        ret = temp & vbTab


        'printing unit
        .Pattern = "[^A-Z_°]"
        Debug.Print .Replace(strInput, "")
        ret = ret & .Replace(strInput, "") & vbTab


        'printing decimal places
        .Pattern = ","
        Debug.Print .Execute(strInput).Count
        ret = ret & CStr(.Execute(strInput).Count)
    End With
    RegExTest = ret
End Function
```

**UPDATE 2**

The function to count decimal places:

```
Function GetDecPlaces(strInput$, Optional decmark$ = ",") As Integer
    'add a reference to
    'Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
    Dim re As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp, mt As Match
    With re
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = decmark & "\d+"
        For Each mt In .Execute(strInput)
            .Pattern = "\d"
            GetDecPlaces = .Execute(mt.Value).Count
        Next mt
    End With
End Function
```

***Hope this helps.***

Comment: The first version works (the second not^^). But two questions. 1) How does `.Execute(strInput).Count` works? --- 2) Can I use the same method to remove everything left from "-" in "20-130°C" to get only "130"?

Comment: Two questions: 1/ `.Execute` method creates a collection `Match` objects (as need to know how many occurances of the given pattern exists within input string), 2/ I have updated my answer.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. I'm sorry but this wasn't the question. I don't wanna know how many commas there are. I want to know how many numbers AFTER a comma there are. I thought this is called *decimal places*, not? For example: 31,333 should give 3 and 31,3 should give 1

Answer (score 1):

Function GetDecPlaces from Cylian could be rewritten without using parameter decmark$.
This can be achieved by the regex character class **[.,]** in the expression "**[.,]**\d+$" (The $ sign means "end of the searchable string"). This allows for both the period decimal and the comma decimal.

```
Function GetDecPlaces(strInput$) As Integer
    'add a reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
    Dim re As New RegExp, mts As MatchCollection, mt As Match
    With re
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "[.,]\d+$"
        Set mts = .Execute(strInput)
        If mts.Count > 0 Then
            Set mt = mts.Item(0)
            .Pattern = "\d"
            Set mts = .Execute(mt.Value)
            GetDecPlaces = mts.Count
        Else
            GetDecPlaces = 0
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for regex here! In fact, you can do this with pure Excel formulas. Assuming your values are in column A, starting in row 2, try the following formulas:

- B2 - remove space: `=SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","")`
- C2 - remove numbers before - : `=IFERROR(MID(B2,SEARCH("-",B2)+1,LEN(B2)-SEARCH("-",B2)),B2)`
- D2 - position of last number: '=MAX(NOT(ISERROR(VALUE(LEFT(C2,ROW($A$2:$A$11)))))*ROW($A$2:$A$11))` (enter as array formula, i.e. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
- E2 - Max value: `=VALUE(LEFT(C2,D2))`
- F2 - Unit: `=RIGHT(C2,LEN(C2)-D2)`
- G2 - decimal places: `=IFERROR(D2-SEARCH(",",C2),0)`

Comment: Sorry, that was not the question. I want to count the numbers after a comma and be as robust as possible against faulty inputs. If I misused words like *decimal places*, feel free to edit my question to clarify this.

Comment: Updated the answer, give it a try! :-)